# Send JSON response from middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

here's the code:

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (Http_Server.mode == 2)
                return InteractivityTask(httpContext);
            else
                return _next(httpContext);
        }

public async Task<HttpResponse> InteractivityTask(HttpContext httpContext) {

            HttpResponse response = httpContext.Response;
            string s = getResponseBody();
            response.Clear();
            MemoryStream ms = GenerateStreamFromString(s);
            response.Body = ms;
            response.ContentType = "application/json";//not sure
            }
            return response;
        }

public MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
        }
```

I am not receiving the body of the response, just the status code with blank body received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.Body.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);
```

Instead of:

```
response.Body = ms;
```